# How to find all records with zero number of has_many assocations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Let's say you have `Question` model with following `has_many` association:(example taken from [this](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading) plugin)

```
has_many :comment_threads, 
         :class_name => "Comment", 
         :as         => :commentable, 
         :dependent  => :destroy
```

How would I define a scope or a class method that returns questions that has no associated comments?

Basically I want `Question.unanswered` to return all questions with zero comments.

Comment: P.s using a counter_cache for now which works but curious how to do this with a select/count statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think approach with `counter_cache` is nicer and faster, but you can create the scope you want like that (you might need some adjustments if I guessed tables or columns names wrong):

```
scope :unanswered, 
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.commentable_id = questions.id').
  where('comments.id IS NULL')
```

Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` generates joined table where for an uncommented question all columns of comments table are set to `NULL`. These are exactly the rows we need so we filter them using `where`.