# How do I get all articles with 0 comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

An article has 1 or many comments. How would I get only the articles with 0 comments?

This would be easier with a counter cache. However, I need to do this without using a counter cache.

Comment: See answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985187/how-to-return-all-records-if-an-assocation-count-is-zero/8986599#8986599).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer on the noted question, also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  scope :without_comments,
         joins(<<-SQL
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (SELECT article_id
                  FROM comments GROUP BY article_id) AS rolled_up_comments
               ON comments.article_id = articles.id
         SQL
         ).
         where("rolled_up_comments.article_id" => nil)
end
```

Use like this:

```
Article.without_comments.all
```

This could easily be adapted to return articles with a specific number or range of comments, e.g.:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  scope :with_comment_count,
         joins(<<-SQL
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (SELECT article_id, COUNT(*) AS comment_count
                  FROM comments GROUP BY article_id) AS rolled_up_comments
               ON comments.article_id = articles.id
         SQL
         )
  scope :with_n_comments, lambda {
           with_comment_count.
           where(:"rolled_up_comments.comment_count" => n)
         }
end
```

In the latter case, `n` can be a specific number, like 100, or a range like `1..10` which ActiveRecord will turn into a `BETWEEN` query returning articles with 1 through 10 comments.

Note that in the 0-comment case, the count is `NULL`, so you can't use the range query for that.

I've tested this in Postgres. I don't know if it'll work in MySQL. I'm not sure how/if MySQL handles sub-selects for joins.

*Edit:* The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985187/how-to-return-all-records-if-an-assocation-count-is-zero/8986599#8986599) pointed out by a previous commenter is easier, if you only need to know articles without comments. For count ranges, the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested by the answer.

Did you try with a scope?

I'm not sure but it could be the solution.

Rails doc : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Scopes will help, but to my knowledge ActiveRecord doesn't include a native mechanism to do this out of the box. You'll need joins. I'm posting something shortly.